# Power set of $\{\varnothing, \{ \varnothing\}\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The power set of $\{\varnothing, \{ \varnothing\}\}$ is defined as follows:
$$\{\varnothing, \{ \varnothing\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\}$$

Why do we have the 3rd element in the answer $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$?

Comment: What is your definition of the power set? Why do you think that $\{\{\phi\}\}$ doesn't fit this definition?

Comment: If we have a set with two elements $X = \{a, b \}$, then the powerset of $X$ is:
$\{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a, b\} \}$, just sub in your elements as $a$ and $b$. I think the fact that the elements in the set are the empty set or the set containing the empty set is confusing you.

Comment: @IntegrateThis. Thank you. Is not $\{\phi\}$ is enough for the second element, which is $\{\phi\}$? Why we have also $\{\{\phi\}\}$?

Comment: @Avra the set containing the empty set is different than the empty set.

Comment: @IntegrateThis. I got that, so $\{\phi\}$ is for the first element and $\{\{\phi\}\}$ is for the second element?

Comment: @Avra yes that's right.

Comment: @IntegrateThis Post your comment(s) as an answer so the OP can accept it so the question won't stay on the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we have a set with two elements $X=\{a,b\}$, then the powerset of $X$ is: $\{∅, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$, just sub in your elements as $a$ and $b$.

I think the fact that the elements in the set are the empty set or the set containing the empty set is what is confusing you.

For more general practice consider $ Y = \emptyset $, then $\mathcal{P}(Y) = \{ \emptyset\}$

Further, let $Z = \{  \emptyset \}$, then  $\mathcal{P}(Z) = \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \}\}$

Comment: unfortunately your second two examples are not correct. $\mathcal{P}(Y)=\{\emptyset\}$ and $\mathcal{P}(Z)=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

Comment: for instance, your claim that $\{\emptyset\}\in\mathcal{P}(Y)$ would mean that $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq\emptyset$, which in turn would mean $\emptyset\in\emptyset$, which is false

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom fixed

Comment: IntegrateThis cool :) (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Power set is the set of all subsets. Each element is a subset of the initial set.

The initial set is $\{\color{red}\emptyset, \color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}}\}$

That is a set with two elements $\color{red}\emptyset$ and $\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}}$

So what are the subsets of a set with two elements.  There are $2^2 =4$ such sets because each element can either be in as set or not.  So the four subsets are:

1. The set with neither $\color{red}\emptyset$ nor $\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}}$.
   That is the set: $\emptyset$
2. The set that has  $\color{red}\emptyset$ but not $\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}}$.
   That is the set: $\{\color{red}\emptyset\}$.
3. The set that does not have $\color{red}\emptyset$ but has $\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}}$
   That is the set: $\{\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}}\}$
4. The set that has both $\color{red}\emptyset$ and $\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}}$.
   That is the set $\{\color{red}\emptyset,\color{blue}{\{\emptyset\}}\}$